# angularjs: $stateChangeStart not fired with same-level nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In app-config i've got this states:

```
$stateProvider               
            .state('main', {
                url: "/main",
                templateUrl: "partials/main.html"
            })
            .state('main.state1',
            {
                url: "^/someurl1",
                templateUrl: "sometemplate.html",
                controller: 'somectrl'

            })
            .state('main.state2',
            {
                url: "^/someurl2",
                templateUrl: "sometemplate2.html",
                controller: 'somectrl2'

            })
            .state('main.state1.substate',
            {
                url: "^/someurl1/substate",
                templateUrl: "sometemlp.html",
                controller: 'substatectrl'
            });
```

then I've got directive in which I watch statechange:

```
     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState , fromParams) {
         //somecode
}
```

the problem is: `$stateChangeStart` fired when I'm going from substate to state1/state2, but isn't fired when i'm going to the same nesting level state, for example: from state1 to state2 or from one substate to another, what can cause this? Is it a bug?

Comment: Refer this if u could get anything from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891218/using-state-methods-with-statechangestart-tostate-and-fromstate-in-angular-ui