# Angular window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a system that have some forms, each one on a state route of angularjs ui-router.

My need is, if have some change on the current form, and the user try to change to another state without save, the system will show a confirmation message like `confirm` of javascript. The result is something like `window.onbeforeunload` on a multi-page app.

Anyone have some way to do that?

PS: I think to show code will not help, but if you need, add some comment..

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you tried.

Comment: @Malkus I've tried use `window.onbeforeunload` but this no make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can object $stateChangeStart to intercept a state change and use preventDefault on the event that triggered the stateChange to prevent the state change if necessary. There's a good solution for this here: 
[Using $state methods with $stateChangeStart toState and fromState in Angular ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891218/using-state-methods-with-statechangestart-tostate-and-fromstate-in-angular-ui#)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can check for ng-pristine class, it will tell you whether the form has been modified by the user or not.
For more details check this link [ng-pristine](http://www.ng-vinod.com/2014/07/angularjs-pristine-dirty-valid-invalid.html)