# how to get data for toState.templateUrl on model run using request $http angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel

how i can run toState.templateUrl in $HTTP request angularjs, i can get data from respons $http, but cant running at toState.templateUrl, but if toState.templateUrl outside from $http its work, please help me.
i need dynamic load templateUrl filename from Database.

config

```
$stateProvider
            .state('auth', {
                url: '/auth',
                templateUrl: '../views/authView.html',
                controller: 'AuthController as auth'
            })
            .state('logout',{
                url: '/logout',
                controller: 'LogoutController as user'
            })
            .state('users', {
                url: '/users',
                templateUrl: '../views/userView.html',
                controller: 'UserController as user'
            })

            ////// List app Menu //
            .state('userMenuAppView', {
                url: '/userMenuAppView',
                templateUrl: '../views/userMenuAppView.html',
                controller: 'UserMenuAppController as user'
            })
            ///// In App /////
            .state('userAppView', {
                url: '/userAppView/:appId',
                templateUrl: '../views/userAppView.html',
                controller: 'userAppViewController as user'
            })
            .state('userSubmenuView', {
                url: '/userAppView/:appId/:appIdSub'
            });
```

run

```
myapps.run(function($rootScope, $auth, $location, $http, $stateParams) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
          if (toState.name === 'userSubmenuView') {
                $http({
                    url: 'api/UserPage',
                    method: "GET",
                    params: {app_id: toParams.appId, app_id_sub: toParams.appIdSub}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    /// *This case problem cant run
                    toState.templateUrl = response+'.html';
                    /// *This case problem cant run

                 }, function errorCallback(response) {

                });
          }

    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you want to change toState?

Comment: for load file html, because i want get filename from my database using $http, sorry if i was wrong, i trying to learning angularjs

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891218/using-state-methods-with-statechangestart-tostate-and-fromstate-in-angular-ui) question. Do not change the toState parameter.

Comment: sorry i cant understand, still learning, please can u give me example for my case